# How can I navigate to a different view controller using UIPickerView

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

I implemented a UIPickerView in my HomeViewController. The UIPickerView has 3 different sections that should correspond to 3 different view controllers. What code do I need to write so that selecting a row from the UIPickerView takes me to the corresponding ViewController?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HomeViewController needs to conform to `UIPickerViewDelegate`:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {
```

Then implement `didSelectRow` delegate method of `UIPickerView`

Assuming you have only one component (so not checking component in method)

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print(row)
    if row == 0 {
        let vcOne = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC") as! FirstVC
        present(vcOne, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // first selection, initialize the VC related with it
    } else if row == 1 {
        let vcTwo = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondVC
        present(vcTwo, animated: true, completion: nil)
        // second selection, initialize the VC related with it
    } else {
        // other selections, you get the idea, you can also do switch-case
    }
}
```

Inside the delegate method you can initialize, and push or present different viewControllers depending on the row.

Comment: Thank you! lets say my ViewControllers are named "FirstVC" , "SecondVC" etc. what code should I write so that row == 0 takes me to 'FirstVC"?

Comment: are those ViewControllers in the same storyboard? If so, give them storyboard identifier, if you dont use storyboard tell me so, I will try to edit my answer.

Comment: they are in the same storyboard

Comment: I  am not sure what to write after: "if row == 0 { "

Comment: See my edited answer, for example: firstVC is identifier you give on storyboard, and FirstVc (with capital first letter) is the class file the viewcontroller file.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, did it work? If so, can you select my answer as accepted? If not, ask me here and I will edit my answer to help you further.

Comment: Quick question. What if the ViewController "FirstVC" is on another storyboard? What code should I use then?

Comment: Then you need to initalize that storyboard as well, lets say that storyboard is called "Login", initializing would be like: `let loginStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)` Then: -- `loginStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC")`